# Connection Lost. Make sure that Qlik Sense is running properly

Tags: qliksense

I am getting this error:

Connection Lost. Make sure that Qlik Sense is running properly. If your session has timed out due to inactivity, refresh to continue working.

Refresh just gets me the same error. I have checked all the logs, and none seem to be getting updated. logging is all on debug.

The port 4747 seems to be working ok. There are only three entries for it when I run netstat -a -p -tcp

TCP    0.0.0.0:4747           qlikserver1:0      LISTENING

...
  TCP    10.0.101.164:4747      qlikserver1:49316  ESTABLISHED

...
  TCP    10.0.101.164:49316     qlikserver1:4747   ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out this obscure message.

I set up the ldap properly in user directory connectors. This required unchecking a strange textbox and only then did the Sync button work.

Then, I set up a token for my ldap user, and he could log in.